# dynamic ui:include with ui:fragment: component with rendered false still make inside component tree

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I am force to use a very old version of MyFaces 2.0.5 I think, and dynamic include with EL cause so much problem, so I switch to static include with ui:fragment

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{filtersPopup.filterFileName == 'checkBoxFilters'}">
    checkBoxFilters
    <ui:include src="/analytics/checkBoxFilters.xhtml" rendered="#{filtersPopup.filter != null}"/>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{filtersPopup.filterFileName == 'DateRelativeFilter'}">
    DateRelativeFilter
    <ui:include src="/analytics/DateRelativeFilter.xhtml" rendered="#{filtersPopup.filter != null}"/>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{filtersPopup.filterFileName == 'listboxFilter'}">
    listboxFilter
    <ui:include src="/analytics/listboxFilter.xhtml" rendered="#{filtersPopup.filter != null}"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

With this, it still complain about duplicate id because I use same id on couples of these source file. So it seems that even `rendered` should be `false`, it still make it to the component tree. However duplicate id is fine. I can fix that easy, so now when I submit form, I got this exception

```
 /analytics/checkBoxFilters.xhtml at line 24 and column 118 value="#{filtersPopup.filter.groups}": Property 'groups' not found on type ListBoxFilter
```

so as you can see from the exception, it `ListBoxFilter` is the object I want, so only include ListBoxFilter.xhtml, but is being accessed `checkBoxFilters.xhtml` hence the error. Any idea how to fix this issue please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<ui:include>` doesn't extend from `UIComponent`. It's a tag handler. It does thus not support the `rendered` attribute at all. It's also nowhere listed in [the tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html).

`<ui:fragment>` is indeed an `UIComponent`. So basically you end up with **all** those 3 include files being included during view build time and thus all 3 physically end up in JSF component tree. It's only the HTML output which is conditionally rendered via `<ui:fragment rendered>`. You still end up with duplicate component IDs from those includes because they all end up in JSF component tree.

You should be using a taghandler like `<c:if>` instead of `<ui:fragment>` to conditionally build the JSF component tree.

So, theoretically, this should do for each of them:

```
<c:if test="#{filtersPopup.filterFileName == 'checkBoxFilters'}">
    checkBoxFilters
    <c:if test="#{filtersPopup.filter != null}">
        <ui:include src="/analytics/checkBoxFilters.xhtml" />
    </c:if>
</c:if>

... etc
```

This has however some caveats when `#{filtersPopup}` is a view scoped bean and/or when you're using `<f:viewParam>`:

1. This requires minimum Mojarra 2.1.18, otherwise JSF view scoped beans will fail to restore.
2. Taghandlers run during view build time. So things which runs thereafter like `<f:viewParam>` won't work at all. You'd need to fall back to manually grabbing HTTP request parameters via `ExternalContext`.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: `filtersPopup` is a SessionScoped, is that good enough, BalusC?

Comment: As to Mojarra version, yes. Only the `<f:viewParam>` problem persists. If `filterFileName` or `filter` (in)directly depend on `<f:viewParam>`, then it will fail.

Comment: Thanks. I think that it works I dont see that issue anymore, but I ran into another one. if I have multiple `c:if` like u have above, when I form submit I ran into this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error restoring component: j_id52
 at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.restoreStateFromMap(DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.java:51 .. Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with javax.faces.component._DeltaList`. If I just have 1 `ui:include` then everything work correct. Any idea, BalusC. Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid that you've to upgrade MyFaces to latest.

Comment: There is no reason why don't upgrade MyFaces to the latest (the latest artifacts are the best ones so far, with lots of improvements and bug fixes).

Comment: @lu4242: as far as I know, OP is using Websphere. The manual upgrade procedure is quite opaque.

Comment: I see. In theory it should be easy to do it, because the integration points has not changed in a long time. Personally I strongly suggest upgrade, because the problem of how to deal with dynamic sections (c:if, ui:include src="#{...}" ...) was solved long time ago and requires changes some code inside jsf, in a way that can't really be avoided.